# Identifying ALL modules loaded by a process in Windows

Tags: c, winapi

I am writing a C++ program which needs to tell me all modules loaded by a given process. I've started looking into [EnumProcessModules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682631%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it warns: "The EnumProcessModules function does not retrieve handles for modules that were loaded with the LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE flag. For more information, see LoadLibraryEx."

Unfortunately, [LoadLibraryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't offer any insights as to how to identify any process loaded in this manner. It only offers that loading it as a data file doesn't prevent any other process from altering the library.

Is there a means to identify libraries dynamically loaded with LoadLibraryEx?

Comment: A library loaded "as datafile" contains no executable code as far as the process is concerned, so it doesn't count as a module. It will be loaded for good during an actual LoadLibrary call on it or on a module that depends on it.

Comment: A library loaded "as datafile" is not treated as a module for bookkeeping purposes. You will not be able to find it via any module enumeration functions because it isn't really a module. (Notice for example that the loader can't event detect duplicate attempts to load "as datafile". That's because loading "as datafile" just means "map it into memory but don't tell anybody.")

Comment: By the way, why do you need to know all the modules loaded by a given process? This is not normally something of interest, and definitely not something you should take dependencies on, since the operating system can introduce new modules or remove existing ones at any time.

Comment: @RaymondChen cuz I wanna dump the modules mate, quit being like that

Comment: @TrisT So just curiosity? Production programs shouldn't be doing this sort of thing because it changes as the operating system changes, and relying on specific modules leads to compatibility issues.

Comment: @RaymondChen no, not curiosity. A production program which has the specific goal of dumping any loaded module. Didn't even need to be that, process explorer does exactly this (with the virtualquery and everything) - that's a production program too. 32-bit .NET DLLs can be loaded into 64 bit processes and ran (because they're 32-bit they get loaded with LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE, but they execute nonetheless), any production debugging or analysis tool **should** be...

Comment: @RaymondChen ...doing this. Hell, visual studio probably does it. So many people in this website behave like you, it's always "because I don't usually do it, you shouldn't ever do it either, it's bad practice". Just at least ask why first before you say "you shouldn't do it".

Comment: @TrisT Okay, it's for diagnostic purposes. That's fine. What's bad is doing things like "I want to do something different if combase.dll is loaded."

Answer (score 5):

1. Enumerate the process' virtual memory with `VirtualQueryEx`.
2. For each `MEM_MAPPED` or `MEM_IMAGE` range, query the mapped filename using `GetMappedFileName` (in kernel32 since Windows 7; for older versions available in PSAPI.DLL).

Comment: I devow my existence to you

Answer (score 1):

`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`'s documentation doesn't mention this limitation (but has other problems with bitness), so it may be worth a try.

Comment: just in case somebody else stumbles on this, unfortunately doesn't work